# Постановка кавычек в названии продукта

Tags: пунктуация

Есть название продукта - пицца «Разработчика». Как писать правильно: с кавычками (пицца «Разработчика») или без (пицца Разработчика)?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что название этого продкута - "Пицца Разработчика". Как пицца "Гавайская" или "Четыре сыра".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта мне кажутся неверными (объяснить, почему?).

Я бы писал `«Пицца разработчика»` (в ценнике, этикетке, меню). Даже в перечне, где присутствует список пицц (и лишние употребления слова «пицца» не нужны), я бы не убирал слово «пицца» (и, тем более, не выносил его за кавычки); потому что тогда возникнет иллюзия, что «разработчика» — это именительный падеж женского рода (как «Маринара», «Маргерита», «Каприччоза»), а не родительный падеж слова мужского рода «разработчик». В обычном тексте тексте считается возможным (и в некоторых случаях даже предпочтительным) употребление названий блюд с маленькой буквы без кавычек, но, поскольку в Вашем случае оно имело бы явную двусмысленность («Он взял себе пиццу разработчика.»), то я бы и тут поостерёгся писать без кавычек.

Хотя если Вы, наоборот, хотите сделать игру слов, создав у посетителя иллюзию того, что что «разработчика» — это слово женского рода (по аналогии с «Маринара», «Маргерита», «Каприччоза»), то тогда: `пицца «Разработчика»` (в меню, этикетке, ценнике) и (допустимо) `пицца Разработчика` в обычном тексте.

Answer (score 1):

В специальной литературе подобные названия пишутся с прописной буквы и без кавычек, а в обычных текстах используются кавычки после приложения, например:

**Пицца Маргарита (Margherita)** - эта пицца впервые была приготовлена в 1899 году, когда королева приехала в Marghereta Napels, чтобы избежать эпидемии холеры на севере Италии. Самая распространенная и традиционная для итальянцев – **пицца «Маргарита»**.

В приведенном примере лучше использовать первый вариант **Пицца разработчика** во всех случаях.